# Hudson + Poll SCM - build upstream projects first?

Tags: java, git, maven-2, hudson

We have a bunch of maven2 projects in Hudson, all set to Poll SCM at the same time.

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be an order in the way it polls and builds the projects.
Ideally it would check the upstream projects first. I could set the poll SCM schedule to account for this, but this seems error-prone as new projects are added.

Right now, sometimes it checks a downstream project "X" first, finds a change and builds with an error. Then when the upstream project "Y" is checked/built, this triggers a build of project X, which is successful. Creating some pointless error notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under "Advanced Project Options", check "Block build when upstream project is building"

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.323 there is an advanced maven build option block-when-upstream-building. Maybe that could be helpful?